# Apply delete-indentation to a whole region

Tags: emacs

The function delete-indentation, usually bound to (M-^), joins the current line to the next one and deletes any indentation.

How do I apply this function to a whole region to join multiple lines in a region?
Or is there another way to achieve the desired result?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `unfill-paragraph`, taken from the [Emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-test/UnfillParagraph).

```lisp
;;; An unfill-paragraph that works in lisp modes
(defun unfill-paragraph (&optional region)
  "Takes a multi-line paragraph and makes it into a single line of text."
  (interactive (progn (barf-if-buffer-read-only) '(t)))
  (let ((fill-column (point-max))
        (emacs-lisp-docstring-fill-column t))
    (fill-paragraph nil region)))
```

If you're willing to give up the prefix argument of the standard <kbd>M-^</kbd>, you could bind the following function to that keyboard shortcut like so:

```lisp
(defun join-line-or-unfill-paragraph (&optional unfill)
  (interactive "P")
  (if unfill (unfill-paragraph) (delete-indentation)))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-^") 'join-line-or-unfill-paragraph)
```

This way, whenever you type <kbd>C-u</kbd> before <kbd>M-^</kbd> the full paragraph will be joined.

Comment: Thank you! That's precisely what I looking for.